# metrics-server:v0.4.2 cannot scrape metrics inside AWS kubernetes cluster environment (cannot validate certificate, doesn't contain any IP SANs)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, metrics-server

Situation:
The metrics-server deployment image is: `k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.4.2`
I have used `kops` tool to deploy a kubernetes cluster into one AWS account.

The error and reason why it is failing, fetched by
`kubectl -n kube-system logs metrics-server-bcc948649-dsnd6`

```
 unable to fully scrape metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from node ip-10-33-47-106.eu-central-1.compute.internal: unable to fetch metrics from node ip-10-33-47-106.eu-central-1.compute.internal: Get "https://10.33.47.106:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true": x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.33.47.106 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs, unable to fully scrape metrics from node ip-10-33-50-109.eu-central-1.compute.internal: unable to fetch metrics from node ip-10-33-50-109.eu-central-1.compute.internal: Get "https://10.33.50.109:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true": x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.33.50.109 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs]
```

I can solve this easy by modifying the metrics-server deployment template, and adding the argument
`- --kubelet-insecure-tls` to the container args, but does not seem production solution.

What I want to ask and learn here is, how can I resolve this in the proper way without losing security ?

Answer (score 2):

Kubelet certificates created by kOps contain only node hostname among their SANs, while metrics server deployed with default manifest is trying to use node private IPs for scraping.  Changing the `kubelet-preferred-address-types` argument resolves this issue:

```
- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=Hostname
```